# Intersection-sets using iterator in Scheme

Tags: object, functional-programming, iterator, scheme

I am trying to create a function that takes two set objects and returns a new set object that is the intersection of those two objects while using an iterator.

Here are some functions that I used, `basic-set1` and `basic-set2` are set objects that are initially empty.

```
((basic-set1 'get-set))
>(d c b a)
((basic-set2 'get-set))
>(a b)
(define my-iterator3 basic-set1)
((my-iterator3 'next))
> d
((my-iterator3 'next))
> c
((my-iterator3 'hasnext))
> #t
```

My desired output

```
(intersection-sets basic-set1 basic-set2)
> (b a)
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
 (define (intersect-sets set1 set2)
  (define my-iterator3 ((set1 'get-iterator )))
  (define result (basic-set))
  (define (iter)
   (let ((x ((my-iterator3 'next))))
    (cond ((not ((my-iterator3 'hasnext))) result)
          (((set2 'element?) x)
          (begin ((result 'insert) x)

                 (iter)))
          (else
           (iter)))))             
  (iter))
```

Tested output:

```
(intersect-sets basic-set1 basic-set2)
>#<procedure:...Problem3.rkt:60:2
```

I'm kind of stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use an iterator? This can be done without one. Check out @Sylwester 's solutions on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129617/how-to-take-intersection-of-pairs-from-two-lists-in-scheme)

Comment: I don't know of any Schemes that have a precise definition for the term "iterator". Could you elaborate on what an iterator is in this context and why you want to use it?

Comment: An iterator is an object that is associated with a collection of data. It provides two
functions, `has-next?` which returns true or false depending on whether there is more data to access,
and `next` which returns some element of the collection

Comment: i have `has-next?` as `hasnext` in my code, i will change that later

Comment: Can we assume the sets are sorted in the same order? Iterator sounds kind of like a queue.

Comment: I don't think we can make that assumption no.

Comment: I don't know if we can, but on further reading of the code it shouldn't matter if the dispatch procedure returned by `(basic-set)` properly handles the message `'element?`

Comment: FYI, `cond` clauses can have more than two parts, and  have and implicit `begin` wrapped around all parts of the clause after the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code is correct.  The first `cond` clause returns `result`, which is a procedure.  If you want the set returned as a list try `((not ((my-iterator3 'hasnext))) ((result 'get-set)))` as your first cond clause in `iter`

Comment: is `'get-result'` the same as my `get-set`?

Comment: hmm I still get the same procedure output. Should I do `get-set` when I call iter at the end of the main function?

Comment: You could do one or the other but not both.  Putting in the cond is a clearer IMHO.  Try sticking another set of parenthsis around it. `((result 'get-set))` I think you implemented it differently then I would have. Your dispatch returns a thunk that returns the value, right? I would have just returned the value directly from the dispatch.

Comment: Ok so I got it to output a list with you what you said above, but the result is `(b)` rather than `(b a)` is there a reason for this?

Comment: Hard telling not knowing, and without your (basic-set) procedure code.  My guess is that 'element? is accidentally modifying the set, or 'insert is not implemented properly.  Alternatively the bug may be in 'has-next improperly saying a set of 1 has no next. Just double check everything. Writing tests may help.

Comment: I think I found what was wrong with it, I didn't check whether the last element in the first set is in the second, because
the iterator will not have a next after assigning x to the last value.